# How to up SQL and compile data frames to a SQL database?

Tags: python

I am new to SQL, I am working on a research project, we have years worth of data from different sources summing up to hundreds of terabytes of data. I currently have them parsed as python data frames, I need help to literally set up SQL from scratch, I also need help to compile all our data into a SQL database. Please tell me everythign I need to know about SQL as a beginner?

Comment: This needs to be more specific - it's not clear if you're asking how to stand up an SQL database or how to start understanding SQL.

The first is a question for ServerFault, and I'd suggest you pick a particular RDMS  first (MySQL vs PostgreSQL vs MSSQL) and consider what you need.

Given that it sounds like you have little experience here, a managed database option (many of the cloud services provide them) may be ideal if there isn't a constraint preventing you from putting your data up on cloud.

As far as using SQL - any textbook will help.

Comment: Though it sounds like SQL-wise, you may be able to get away with a simple INSERT to load the data in (or, if the data is quite large, look into using the bulk loader provided as part of your chosen RDMS).

Comment: @AdamLuchjenbroers, Thank you so much for your comment. Sir, if possible we would like to meet our data local, we do not lack storage space. We eventually intend to clean up the data and apply a machine learning algorithm with all the available data. Based on your experience what do you think would be the best SQL database management system for a beginner and the specifications of this project?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest to get started with one of the free RDMS options, MySQL (https://www.mysql.com/) or PostgreSQL (https://www.postgresql.org/).

Once you've got that installed and configured, and have created the tables you wish to load, you can go with one of two routes to get your data in.

Either you can install the appropriate python libraries to connect to the server you've installed and then INSERT the data in.

Or, if there is a lot of data, look at dumping the data out into a flat file (.csv) and then use the bulk loader to push it into your tables (this is more hassle, but for larger data sets it will be faster).